# Client architecture for calling Spring based web service

Tags: java, spring, swing, model-view-controller, oop

I have written a SOAP based web service which runs fine on a Tomcat server. The Web Service service itself is a Spring MVC based web service that runs on the Tomcat application server.

Now i need to write a Thick client which will be a standalone Java app that will use the services of the web service. I think i am correct in that the client only needs to know about the service details (i.e. operations) and nothing else.

What i am not sure of is the architecture and environment i should use for the client. The client application will be based on Swing but is it possible to use Spring with Swing together?

On the web service i have the following setup

view --> Service --> Model

The client application is basically a configuration tool. It uses the web service to configure user accounts. This means that the client application does not actually write anything to any database. It just uses the services of the web service to make changes to 'user account' and probably view list of accounts.

My question really is
- Is an MVC design suitable for such a use case 
- Usually Spring is used for web based applications. Is there any benefit in using Spring with the Swing based client?
- Are there any alternative or better solutions/design/architecture that would achieve the same?

An example showing Spring used in conjunction with a Swing application would be very usefull.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring MVC is not appropriate for a Swing-based client.  Use the core Spring framework and a JAX-RS implementation like Jersey to provide simple REST web services in tomcat.  Jersey also provides a corresponding client API that you can use within your Swing application to invoke the REST services.

Comment: The web service is already implemented so i am not worried about that. I am only curious as to what architecture i should use for the client application which is Swing based. Thanks

Comment: Is the web service REST or SOAP based?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2410879/lightweight-soap-client-library-for-java

Answer (score 2):

If you have decided upon Swing as your platform, there are two options you can look at:

(1) Net Beans Rich Client Platform

http://netbeans.org/kb/trails/platform.html

(2) You can roll up your sleeves and write your own app using a low level yet extremely flexible framework called Swixml

http://www.swixml.org/

Give Swixml a good try before you try others, it may surprise you.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement Swing-based thin client application with [Spring Integration](http://www.springsource.org/spring-integration) backend serving as a integration tier. It can expose gateways accepting simple Java types or DTOs. Your Swing presenters / controllers interacts with these components in order to call remote webservices.